# Proper way of deallocating memory in SLL?

Tags: c++, linked-list, memory-management

So I'm making my own singly linked list class, with methods that you'd expect such as `remove()` and `insert()`. I don't use pointers that much (almost never), so I thought by making a SLL class it would be good practice for me. But I'm not sure if I'm deallocating my memory correctly.

Here's the structure of my SLL:

```cpp
class singly_linked_list
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Node* next;
        int value;
    };

private:
    int _length;
    Node* head;

public:
    ~singly_linked_list();

public:
    void remove(int index);
    void remove_front();
    void remove_back();
};
```

I'm most concerned about the destructor, and the three remove methods, and those are the ones deallocating memory, and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Here's their definitions:

```cpp
class singly_linked_list
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Node* next;
        int value;
    };

private:
    int _length;
    Node* head;

public:
    ~singly_linked_list()
    {
        Node* node_ptr = head;
        for (int a = 0; a < _length; ++a)
        {
            node_ptr = node_ptr->next;

            delete head;
            head = node_ptr;
        }
    }

public:
    void remove(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= _length)
            throw "index is out of range";

        if (index == 0)
        {
            this->remove_front();
            return;
        }

        Node* node_ptr = head;
        for (int a = 0; a < index - 1; ++a)
            head = head->next;

        Node* temp = head->next;
        head->next = temp->next;
        delete temp;

        _length -= 1;
    }

    void remove_front()
    {
        if (_length == 1)
        {
            // should I delete head instead?
            head = nullptr; // delete head;
            _length = 0;

            return;
        }

        Node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;

        _length -= 1;
    }

    void remove_back()
    {
        if (_length == 1)
        {
            head = nullptr;
            _length = 0;

            return;
        }

        Node* node_ptr = head;
        for (int a = 0; a < _length - 2; ++a)
            node_ptr = node_ptr->next;

        Node* temp = node_ptr->next;
        node_ptr->next = nullptr;
        delete temp;

        _length -= 1;
    }
};
```

I checked a few other questions including [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134874/linked-list-design-and-implementation-c), but it didn't go too much in depth on memory management.

So a couple questions:

1. Am I causing any memory leaks, and is there a better, safer way to do things?
2. In `remove_front()`, should I set `head` to `nullptr`, or should I delete it instead?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the entire class, without the constructor(s) and the insert functions this code really can' be reviewed. The private variables are meaningless without the constructor and the insert functions.

Comment: If you want to learn how to make lists is fine and a good exercise, but if you want to build software that is well written in c++ use the standard library stl and use std::list instead of building your own list.

Comment: *"Am I causing any memory leaks,"* @DynamicSquid consider using leak sanitizer http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html

Comment: @camp0 Like I said in my post, I'm doing this just to practice, but yes, I would use STL in an actual application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answers to your questions

> Am I causing any memory leaks, and is there a better, safer way to do things?

Yes, see for example your second question. A safer way is to use something like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to manage pointers for you.

> In remove_front(), should I set head to nullptr, or should I delete it instead?

You should delete it of course. If you just set `head` to `nullptr`, the memory for the head node is still allocated.

## Avoid using names that start with an underscore

Names that start with underscores are reserved for the standard library. There are [some more specific rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), but in general it is best to avoid them completely. You can safely append an underscore to the end of a name though.

On the other hand, while you have `_length`, `head` is written without an underscore. If you are not consistent in marking private variables with an underscore, there is not much point to it at all.

## Flawed logic in `remove(int index)`

There is an issue with the `for`-loop in `remove(int index)`: you are moving the head pointer instead of `node_ptr`. In fact you are not using `node_ptr` at all after initializing it. The compiler should have given you a warning about this (be sure to enable compiler warnings and fix them).

To make this work correctly, even when removing the head node, you should use an extra layer of redirection: you want a pointer to the pointer you need to update, like so:

```
Node **node_ptr = &head;           // node_ptr is pointing to the variable `head`
for (int a = 0; a < index - 1; ++a)
    node_ptr = &(*node_ptr)->next; // node_ptr is updated to point to some node's `next` variable

Node* temp = *node_ptr;            // get the actual Node pointer to
*node_ptr = (*node_ptr)->next;     // update `head` or a `next` to skip one Node
delete temp;                       // delete the target Node
```

Once you grasp this you've become a two-star programmer!

## Unnecessary code duplication

You have three different functions for removing an element, but they all do mostly the same. In fact, the first one, `remove(int index)`, does everything you need. You don't need to treat `index == 0` as a special case, the code will work correctly anyway. You can make `remove_front()` and `remove_back()` call the generic `remove()` function:

```
void remove(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= _length)
        throw "index is out of range";

    Node **node_ptr = &head;
    for (int a = 0; a < index - 1; ++a)
        node_ptr = &(*node_ptr)->next;

    Node* temp = *node_ptr;
    *node_ptr = (*node_ptr)->next;
    delete temp;

    _length -= 1;
}

void remove_front()
{
    remove(0);
}

void remove_back()
{
    remove(_length - 1);
}
```